# Open Custom Keyboard Extension when specific UITextField become first responder

Tags: ios, objective-c, custom-keyboard, ios-keyboard-extension

Is it possible to open only my custom keyboard in container app when a textfield in the container app becomes first responder? And how do i detect if system keyboard appeared instead of custom keyboard?

Comment: this is custom view as inputView not keyboard extension

Comment: Hey man, did you understand the question ? my custom keyboard is working fine. tying to find a way to detect if my custom keyboard appeared or the system keyboard appeared when textfield first responder in container app.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the customkeyboardView as an inputView of the UITextField as indicated below

```
textField.inputView = customkeyboardView
```

Comment: container app has no direct access of its extension app. r u sure what you said? please help me.